# What is the difference between I2C and PS2 mode?

Tags: hardware, touchpad

On my Dell XPS 13 9343 my touchpad can work with I2C bus or in PS2 mode.

What is the difference between those two modes ? Why are they both available ?

---

The output of `xinput` is :

```
 Virtual core pointer                           id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

`DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN` is the touchpad using I2C bus.

Comment: I am interested, too

Answer (score 2):

I2C is newer, allows for multi-touch gestures, and usually connects directly to the PCH- most modern devices will switch to I2C drivers once the OS loads.

PS2 is kept for redundancy and compatibility. Usually PS2 is connected to the Embedded Controller for modern devices. Most UEFI bioses only accept touchpad input through PS2, and OSes will revert back to PS2 connection if there are issues with I2C.